# ---Lights out---

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Little puzzle.

Instructions:

- all
- don't repeat

[image]

Hint

> Added the knowledge tag. Knowledge most of you most likely have...

Hint2

> Make sense of the upper grid first. Why are some lines oriented in the same way and some aren't? What can the grid possibly represent?

Comment: Rot13(Vf "gur zrffntr vf (x)avtug (x)avtug" gur svany fbyhgvba?)

Comment: @LukasRotter Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The top image

> represents the initial positions of chess pieces. Different rotations represent different pieces. So this obviously means we have to do something chess-related :)
>  [image]

As for the 4x3 grid:

> The instructions presented in the question are "all" and "don't repeat". Combining this with chess points us towards a [Knight's Tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) - A sequence of chess knight moves that visits each square on a board exactly once.
>  The 4x3 grid should be thought of as two separate grids: One with the left-hand letters of the original, and the other one with the right-hand letters. Now take the left letters and the following knight's tour (starting position is the divided cell in the original image):
>  [image]
>  Taking the letters in the given order yields `the message is`.
>  And doing the mirrored version of the tour above on the right letters yields `knight knight`:
>  [image]

So the final message is

> "The message is knight knight", a wordplay on "night night" ("Lights out")

Comment: Well done! rot13(Nygubhtu zl vagragvba jnf gjb qvssrerag ebhgf (gur gjb bayl jnlf cbffvoyr - zveeberq cngujnlf) obgu fgnegvat sebz gur fdhner jvgu gur ubevmbagny yvar. Bar raqf nobir gur yvar juvpu fcryyf bhg gur svefg cneg, naq gur bgure raqf orybj gur yvar juvpu fcryyf bhg gur frpbaq cneg.)